# Django REST Framework PATCH request using a query instead of ID or PK

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have a *Building* model for which I have created a Serializer and ModelViewSet.

I can update a model by sending a PATCH request and specifying a **model ID** as follows:

```
curl http://127.0.0.1/dashboard/api/v1/buildings/3/ \
--request PATCH \
--header "Content-Type: application/json" \
--data '{"name": "School","address": "123 Some Street","description": "A place to learn"}'
```

How do I update a building model by **querying a field** instead of passing a model ID? For instance:

```
curl http://127.0.0.1/dashboard/api/v1/buildings/?name=hospital \
--request PATCH \
--header "Content-Type: application/json" \
--data '{"name": "School","address": "123 Some Street","description": "A place to learn"}'
```

*Note, building names are unique!*

This functionality would be very useful as the client often does not know the model ID, but rather attributes of the model it wishes to update.

---

**views.py**

```
class APIBuildingsViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Building.objects.all()
    serializer_class = BuildingSerializer
    filter_backends = [DjangoFilterBackend]
    filterset_fields = ['name', 'address']
```

**models.py**

```
class Building(models.Model):
    building_id = models.AutoField('ID', auto_created=True, primary_key=True)
    name        = models.CharField('Name', max_length=125, null=True, blank=False, unique=True)
    address     = models.CharField('Address', max_length=256, null=False, blank=False)
    user_id     = models.ForeignKey('accounts.User', on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=1)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

**serializers.py**

```
class BuildingSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Building
        fields = ('building_id', 'name', 'address', 'user_id')
```

**urls.py**

```
router = DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'buildings', views.APIBuildingsViewSet, base_name='buildings')

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^api/', include(router.urls)),
]
```

Comment: What's wrong with letting the client look up the id first?  Then they can decide how to handle the case where multiple buildings have the same name.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with that approach. I was just hoping for a way to let the client update a building with one API request rather than two (first request gets the pk of a building, and second request updates that building)

Answer (score 0):

You can set up your [`lookup_field` to be `name`](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#attributes) inside your `ModelViewSet`:

```
class APIBuildingsViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Building.objects.all()
    serializer_class = BuildingSerializer
    filter_backends = [DjangoFilterBackend]
    filterset_fields = ['name', 'address']
    lookup_field = 'name'
```

Then you can access a detail route using the building `name`: `/api/v1/buildings/hospital/`

Comment: I haven't tried it, but can you set `lookup_field` to a non-unique field?  Seems dangerous.

Comment: @RishiG I just gave this a go, and no, you cannot use this method for non-unique fields

Comment: it'll break when trying to retrieve the object (in cases where there's multiple objects with that same value for the field).